# Anonymous C struct with declaration

Tags: c, struct, anonymous, anonymous-struct

Considering the following definition:

```
struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} point;


void main()
{ 
    ...
}
```

You're declaring the variable "point" of "anonymous struct" type, is there any way to declare another variable of the same type outside the struct definition (maybe in main function)?

Comment: In C++ it is actually possible to reuse anonymous types thanks to `decltype`. But that doesn't exist in C, nor does any kind of type deduction for that matter.

Comment: Thanks! Is a little confusing when you try to learn C and C++, but right now i'm focused on C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't, at least not in standard C. If you want to use the type, you have to give it a name.

Answer (score 2):

In standard C? No, you can't do that.  But there are compiler extensions:

```
typeof(point) myPoint;
```

in clang and GCC, for example.

Editorial note:  `main()` should return `int`.

Comment: That is just what i need to know, i use standard C and i investigate previously if is anyway to do and i find that visual c++ has an extension (but is C++ from Microsoft, not standard and no C). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you're asking, maybe:

```
void main()
{ 
    point p;
}
```

Also see http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm

Comment: No, the compiler (gcc) throws an error. Just that the question, i want to know if exist any way to declare another variable of the same type as "point", but keep in mind that "point" is a variable not a type and not an alias.

Comment: Int this case, the compiler throws 2 errors: 1) expected ";" before "p" 2) Use of undeclarate variable "p".

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do, but if you just want it to compile: http://pastebin.com/CRfdDj4E http://codepad.org/uvYWG6WB

Comment: From the variable "point" data type is unknown, is anyway to declare another variable of the same data type as "point" inside the main function?

Comment: You're trying to get type of 'p', right? That's impossible in C, at runtime that information is lost.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to get that type. Thanks! ;-)