# Get type of instantiated unnamed struct

Tags: c++, struct, anonymous-types

I'm writing an app in C++ that interfaces with some code written in C.

The following is a simplified version of a struct defined in C code that I can't modify.

```
struct event{
    uint8_t type;
    union {
        struct /* WishThisHadAName */ {
            // ...
        } connect;
        struct {
            // ...
        } disconnect;
    };
};
```

I'm trying to be able to define functions that take a pointer to the different unnamed structs, connect, disconnect, and all the others not listed above. To look something like the following.

```
void onConnect( struct WishThisHadAName *evt );
```

Is it possible to create this prototype without modifying the original C struct? Is there an easy way to create a wrapper for the unnamed structs to give them a name? Am I forced to create named structs that mirror the unnamed ones I'm trying to use?

I know you can get the type of an instantiated variable with `decltype` but I can't figure out how I could use that or `declval` in order to create the function prototype I'm looking for.

Comment: `template <typename T> void onConnect( T* evt );`?

Comment: Note that, if you weren't using C++, with its lovely `decltype` operator`,  there would be no solution. [This is not possible in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725502/anonymous-c-struct-with-declaration).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple as `using event_connect_t = decltype(event::connect);`.

Then you can use it as `void onConnect( event_connect_t *evt );`.

You can't declare a compatible type, but you can just extract the existing type declaration from the definition. `decltype` can resolve static member references just fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a compiler such as gcc/g++, you can use `typeof` to create a typedef for the anonymous type:

```cpp
typedef __typeof__(((struct event){0}).connect) conn_type;
typedef __typeof__(((struct event){0}).disconnect) disconn_type;
```

Or without compound literals:

```cpp
struct event e;
typedef __typeof__(e.connect) t1;
typedef __typeof__(e.disconnect) t2;
```